# Unable to Connect Raspbian Lite to Enterprise Wifi

Tags: networking, raspbian-buster, raspbian-lite, wpa-supplicant

for the last few days I have been trying to connect my raspberry pi 3B to an enterprise wifi network with little success. My wpa_supplicant.conf looks like:

```
network={
        ssid="(My Network SSID)"
        key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
        identity="My_Identity"
        password="My_Password"
        phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
}
```

I also downgraded my wpasupplicant from 2.7 to 2.4 as I read somewhere that 2.7 had issues with wpa2 enterprise networks. Now when I run wpa_supplicant -v it says wpa_supplicant v2.4. I think it is managing to connect to my network and dns works but I still don't have an internet connection because when I try to do something like ping google.com it shows an ip but I get 100% packet loss.
If I manually terminate wpasupplicant and restart it with:

```
wpa_supplicant -Dnl80211 -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

I get the following:

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wlan0: Trying to associate with SSID '(My Network SSID)'
wlan0: Associated with (MAC Address of nearest AP)
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
p2p-dev-wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=GB
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=25
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-METHOD EAP vendor 0 method 25 (PEAP) selected
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=2 subject='/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2' hash=(A Hash)
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=1 subject='/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2' hash=(A Hash)
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=0 subject='/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=(Enterprise Website)' hash=(A Hash)
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-ALT depth=0 DNS:(Enterprise Website)
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-ALT depth=0 DNS:(Enterprise Website)
EAP-MSCHAPV2: Authentication succeeded
EAP-TLV: TLV Result - Success - EAP-TLV/Phase2 Completed
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-SUCCESS EAP authentication completed successfully
wlan0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with (MAC Address of nearest AP) [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to (MAC Address of nearest AP) [id=0 id_str=]
```

Furthermore running iwconfig wlan0 shows:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:(My Network SSID)  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: (MAC Address of nearest AP)   
          Bit Rate=39 Mb/s   Tx-Power=31 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=40/70  Signal level=-70 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:8  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

When I try to use apt-get install I keep getting: Unable to fetch some archives.
Any help in fixing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you get a valid IP address and gateway address?

Comment: @Andyroo ifconfig gives lo: 127.0.0.1 and wlan0 inet: 10.108.1.193 and broadcast: 10.108.7.255 and netmask: 255.255.248.0

Comment: Try `sudo apt update` and see if it goes OK. Have you changed your sources file for updates at all?

Comment: Doing apt-get update works fine. I changed my sources from buster to stretch for downgrading wpasupplicant but then put wpasupplicant on hold and changed the sources back to buster. Doing upgrade or apt-get install, however, says that some directories could not be retrieved.

Comment: Directories or Packages?  Its possibly the network has a block on some sites - I would get the IT team to check.

Comment: Have you asked the helpdesk for your corporate network to help? That's what they're paid for.

Comment: Packages sorry. It is not really within the usage policy so I doubt that the IT team would help that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your answers. I never managed to properly get dhcpcd and wpasupplicant to work but I noticed that wpa2-enterprise networks works well with the ubuntu + mate environment supplied on the raspberry pi website. It looked like it was using network manager so what I did was go back to raspbian lite and run:

```
sudo apt install network-manager network-manager-gnome
```

Then:

```
sudo apt purge openresolv dhcpcd5
```

I was then able to setup my enterprise network and it connected and everything worked as wanted. I was trying to do all of this in order to then connect to a vpn subscription then create an access point so that I could connect devices such as an Alexa to the internet which do not support enterprise networks.

Comment: Please mark the answer as the accepted one with a click on the tick on its left side. That prevents your Question from being shown as a unsolved Post to the community and saves them/us a lot of work.